# Simple example to illustrate how to create trigger (selecting a value from dropdown list) to open a specific sidebar in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a dropdown list in google sheets.  I have also created functions that call different sidebars.  It would be great if someone could provide a simple example of how I could set it up so when I select a value from a dropdown list, it would trigger the opening of a specific sidebar (call a specific function).

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! To help others achieving a better solution for your problem please share more information about your issue on your post, code snippets of what you have tried so far.

Comment: Will do. Thanks for the guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy sample:

```
function Edit(e) {
  if(e.range.getColumn()==1 && e.value=="Yes"){
    showSidebar1();
  }
  else if(e.range.getColumn()==1 && e.value=="No"){
    showSidebar2();
  }
}
```

You have to

- define your column of interest (e.g. column 1)
- specify which function shall be run depending on the chosen value (hereby it does not matter either the value has been chosen from a dropdown or typed in)
- bind to the function an [installable](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) `onEdit` trigger (simple trigger won't be able to open sidebars
- befine the functions `showSidebar1();`, `showSidebar2();` etc. as following:

```
function showSidebar1() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Page1')
  .setTitle('My custom sidebar')
  .setWidth(300);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or SlidesApp or FormApp.
  .showSidebar(html);
}
```

Comment: Many thanks. That looks logical. I will give it a shot. Thanks